# Recommended data structure or table schema for efficient lookup/evaluation of association rules?

Tags: php, postgresql, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

For a recent project I implemented the FP-Growth algorithm for reading in transactions and generating common sets, from which I then generate association rules.  This is working well for my purposes.

Now that I'm generating thousands of rules, I am looking for an efficient way to execute them...  currently I'm storing the rules in a postgres table where the body is an array of integers and the head is a single int.  My query looks for rows where the set of items I've got contains the body but not the head.

I'm limited to using PHP and Postgres - this project is a small part of a much larger application.

Could anyone recommend a data structure or table schema / direct me to some good resources?  Also, what is the preferred term when discussing the application of association rules - evaluate, execute, lookup, run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you have a set of rules where each of left side described as set of predicates.
One option is to just index them with boolean search engine like Lucene, and then given set of predicates applied to current event you can search for possible rules and then trying to apply them exactly, I'am sure it will work very fast.

Other option is sort you predicates and convert each rule to rule left side string (P1 P2 P3 P4). Now we come to field of many string matching at once, and can use Prefix tree for that (one problem that we should search for substring not exact much but it is also O(log(n)) by complexity)